# compiling data, what to do when there is a missing value when web scraping?

Tags: r, database, web-scraping

I have a couple of questions.

I am scraping data from a journal and trying to compile it into a dataset. The issue that I have had when compiling is null values for some of the html objects I am scraping.

```
page1<-read_html("http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.3102/0013189X08317501")
author <- html_text(html_nodes(page1, '.art_authors'))
year <- html_text(html_nodes(page1, '.year'))
journalName <- html_text(html_nodes(page1, '.journalName'))
art_title <- html_text(html_nodes(page1, '.art_title'))
volume <- html_text(html_nodes(page1, '.volume'))
page <- html_text(html_nodes(page1, '.page'))
email <- html_text(html_nodes(page1, xpath = "//a[@class = 'email']"))
row1<-cbind(author, year, journalName, art_title, volume, page, email)

page2<-read_html("http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.3102/0013189X037002102")
author <- html_text(html_nodes(page2, '.art_authors'))
year <- html_text(html_nodes(page2, '.year'))
journalName <- html_text(html_nodes(page2, '.journalName'))
art_title <- html_text(html_nodes(page2, '.art_title'))
volume <- html_text(html_nodes(page2, '.volume'))
page <- html_text(html_nodes(page2, '.page'))
email <- html_text(html_nodes(page2, xpath = "//a[@class = 'email']"))
row2<-cbind(author, year, journalName, art_title, volume, page, email)

page3<-read_html("http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.3102/0013189X037002104")
author <- html_text(html_nodes(page3, '.art_authors'))
year <- html_text(html_nodes(page3, '.year'))
journalName <- html_text(html_nodes(page3, '.journalName'))
art_title <- html_text(html_nodes(page3, '.art_title'))
volume <- html_text(html_nodes(page3, '.volume'))
page <- html_text(html_nodes(page3, '.page'))
email <- html_text(html_nodes(page3, xpath = "//a[@class = 'email']"))
row3<-cbind(author, year, journalName, art_title, volume, page, email)
View (row3)

a <- rbind (row1, row2, row3)
```

So this turns up as a problem because the third article is missing their email.

One other problem I have, I have a list with all the

```
pagex<-read_html("http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/xxxx/xxxxxxx")
```

ready for implementation. But I there has to be a better way than to manually change all the lines of code for each entry since the order is sequential. I am just not certain what to do.

Comment: This is absolutely a programming question @g5w

Comment: OP: there are dozens of similar questions with answes which ones didnt help?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the question, you can just write an if-else condition for each of the scraping nodes so that you assign a default value in case the field is missing.

Also, instead of calling the three pages separately, you can save all the urls in a list and loop over them the length of the list and save it to a data frame inside the loop.